# How to get rid of unity directory not found error

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have annoying problem within unity. I think its nothing special but i dont know if it will not cause a problem later in project.

[image: Problem within unity across versions]

I tried reinstalling unity and unity hub. Tried to use another version. Error still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your problem is caused by using comma in project name. Typically you should not do that.

[image]

Comment: That´s all ? No way... :D I made new project and error is gone. I feel like total idiot :D Thank you very much :)